# Can backticks be written in minted?

Tags: minted

I have a piece of code I would like to write inside a `minted` syntax highlighting block. The following code works:

```
\begin{minted}[linenos]{go}
...
PasswordHash string
...
\end{minted}
```

But once I write "json:"password-hash" with backticks instead of quotation marks around it (can't even use them here), I get an error "Command \textasciigrave unavailable in encoding OT1." Any idea why this might be?

(If it is relavent, I'm writing this document on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project))

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was, although I don't know at all why this *is* a problem. I was using the package `underscore` to automatically escape underscores, but this meant that any backtick characters in a `\begin{minted}` block would cause an error when compiling.

Comment: You could also ask another question (or edit your previous one, deleting the answer) asking why it happens.